# Why does decoder stop while decoding attributed string with secure coding?

Tags: cocoa

I am still struggling with secure coding an attributed string. As soon as I encode an attributed string with attributes – like
`NSDictionary *attrsDictNormal = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:schrift2, NSFontAttributeName, style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];`

the decoder stops decoding. I know, the attributes are in a dictionary, and I have to name all classes that could be in the dictionary. I try to set the classes

`NSSet *classesAttrText = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSAttributedString class], [NSString class], [NSMutableString class], [NSTextTab class], [NSParagraphStyle class], [NSColor class], [NSMutableParagraphStyle class], [NSFont class], [NSData class], [NSNumber class], [NSDictionary class], [NSArray class], [NSFontDescriptor class], [NSCharacterSet class], [NSConstantString class], [NSTextStorage class], [NSShadow class], [NSGlyphInfo class], nil];`

and then

`[self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:classesAttrText forKey:@"outputText"] forKey:@"outputText"];`

Of course, I have set +(BOOL)supportsSecureCoding to YES everywhere.

I looks clumsy, and it still doesn't work. Which classes did I forget? Or how can I see what the problem is? I do not see anything the decoder does. There are no error messages thrown or logged, it just doesn't decode. After that all decoded objects are getting nil. How can I get into the decoder to see, why and where it stops?

Any help?

Comment: Can you post a small example that demonstrates this? I can't reproduce it. My attributed strings encode and decode fine under SecureCoding with attributes. I don't need to do anything particularly special except set `supportsSecureCoding` in one place. There's no need for a long list of accepted classes. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/93cb1e5fe4953e04a4ac9f2476893fb8

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, in this easy case it works fine. But, if I add some tabs to my attributed string, it does not work any more. I generate an attributed string programmatically with custom decimal tabs and some other stuff. I think, it's an issue like in [link](https://cocoa-dev.apple.narkive.com/eb2L2NYp/nssecurecoding-nsattributedstring)

Comment: See here: https://github.com/axBeGer/Decoding-issue/blob/main/ToEncode.m

Comment: I agree that your link describes the situation well. I recommend rewriting your question using your gist; it reproduces your issue easily (though interestingly on NSCharacterSet). I expect there may be no direct solution, as the cocoa-dev list noted. But posting a working example of the problem will help if others have anything beyond what cocoa-dev determined.

Comment: Why do you think the problem lies in NSCharacter set? NSCharacter conforms to NSSecure coding, too. – I cannot believe that no one, who uses attributed strings – like Apple itself in Pages or Textedit – uses secure coding. How do they do it?

Comment: It's almost certainly that NSAttributedString itself does not implement NSSecureCoding correctly. It's up to NSAttributedString to list all the classes it can deserialize. You passing it at the top level doesn't achieve that. I don't believe that Pages uses NSCoding on NSAttributedStrings (look at the internal `.iwa` files; they don't look like NSKeyedArchiver output). NSTextEdit definitely doesn't.

Comment: IWA (iWork Archive files) are protobuf: https://github.com/obriensp/iWorkFileFormat/blob/master/Docs/index.md#iwa (`.pages` files are actually ZIP)